# new Number() or parseInt() in javascript

Tags: javascript, casting, type-conversion

jshint suggests not to use the constructor new Number( )

but what really are the differences, pros and cons of using one or another

```
var x = new Number("23");
```

or

```
var y = parseInt("42");
```